# Get List of discoverable Bluetooth devices and already paired devices in iOS using CoreBluetooth Framework?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am trying to get the list of all the nearby bluetooth device and paired device of any kind of bluetooth device in IOS8 and above using CoreBluetooth framework. I am using below method to get the list of all the nearby available bluetooth device but the method is not being called.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Start up the CBCentralManager
    _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    // And somewhere to store the incoming data
    _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        // In a real app, you'd deal with all the states correctly
        return;
    }

    // The state must be CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn...
    // ... so start scanning
    [self scan];
}


- (void)scan
{
    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
                                                options:nil];

    NSLog(@"Scanning started");
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central 
     didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral 
         advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData 
                      RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
      NSString *thePeripheralName = peripheral.name;
}
```

I am able to perform both the tasks using BluetoothManager Framework but that is private framework of Apple and Apple Itunes will not approve my application to publish live.

Comment: Are you asking about classic Bluetooth devices or Bluetooth Low Energy (4.0/Smart) peripherals? If "classic", you have to be a member of Apple's MFi program (extra cost and approval required) and use the External Accessory framework to access the devices. If 4.0/Smart/LE, then show how you create and configure the Central and how you're scanning for peripherals.

Comment: I have update my code, please check it out and let me know where am I doing anything wrong also I am using Bluetooth Low Energy (4.0/Smart) peripherals

Comment: I know you simplified for the sake of this post (and in general that's appreciated) though you're missing an important case in this example: case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized in centralManagerDidUpdateState. Make sure you have that in your real code and that you're authorized. So, the real question: are you certain that your scanning is starting? If so, are you certain that you have _one_ verifiable device that you will find? (You can use the app LightBlue from the App Store to verify as this does exactly what you describe, finds all BTLE broadcasters.)

Comment: I have downloaded the LightBlue app and its not able to find any bluetooth device. Please suggest me any other reference

Comment: If LightBlue doesn't find any devices, then your first problem is on the device side. Either it/they are not BTLE, they're not on, they're not broadcasting, etc. Why this may be the case is not a generic problem; it will be specific to each device/device type. If you want to name the make, model, and revision (if there is one) of _one_ device you're trying to "discover", there may be a way to troubleshoot that.

Comment: I have use iphone6 with IOS8.3 and it didn't find any devices.

Comment: Thank you; that could be useful, but that's not the device I'm talking about -- I'm talking about the Bluetooth devices - the one(s) you're "not finding".

Comment: thanks; Other bluetooth devices also ios devices like iphone, ipod , mac etc. but none of devices are find by the app.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think you're going to be able to get help yet. At this point, you don't really have an _appropriate_, clearly articulated question. You have no verified broadcasting BTLE devices, so it's too early to even know if the code you reference above is broken. There are many basic examples of making an iOS device a BTLE peripheral available on the web. Grab one, compile it, and when you have a peripheral (iPod, iPhone, etc) that can be detected by **LightBlue** return to your original question, see if you're still having issues, then re-request help.